# gulp default order of concatenating files

Tags: gulp, build-process

What's the default order the gulp follows when concatenating files.

What's the default order, file names in Alphabetical or any other criterion.

I'm using

```
var concat = require("gulp-concat");

var js = [
            path + "js/common/**/*.js",
            path + "js/modules/**/*.js",
            path + "js/shell/**/*.js"
        ];

        gulp.src(js)
            .pipe(concat("app.min.js"))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(path + "js"));
```

I understand there's a utility out there to control the order but I'm interested to know the default behavior.

I attempted with renaming file names but order of concatenation didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

It will concatinate files in Alphabetical order inside of each element of your `js` array *(because of `*`)* while elements will follow in order of Declaration.

From [gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) docs:

> Files will be concatenated in the order that they are specified in the
>    gulp.src function. For example, to concat .`/lib/file3.js`,
>    `./lib/file1.js` and `./lib/file2.js` in that order, the following code
>    will create a task to do that:
>
> ```
> var concat = require('gulp-concat'); 
>
> gulp.task('scripts', function(){
>    return gulp.src(['./lib/file3.js', './lib/file1.js', './lib/file2.js'])
>      .pipe(concat('all.js'))
>      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/')); });
> ```

By the way, there is a [gulp-order](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-order) plugin which can reorder a stream of files

Comment: in my attempts, the alphabetical file naming didn't have an impact, I'd change the file name and add letter `z` in the beginning to manually enforce an order but the file kept on adding to the top of the concatenated file, however, when I added number `1` to a file, it did got added in the beginning, the point is order within alphabetical names didn't change